# Return True, False and None in Python

Tags: python

I have function `a` call function `b` (returns `True` or `False` to `a`), afterwards function `a` can return the result to be printed.

```
class C:
    ...

    def a(self, data):

        p = self.head
        return self.b( p,data)

    def b(self, p, data):

        current = p
        if current.data == data:
            return True
        else:
            return False


if __name__=="__main__":  

    x = C()
    print(x.a(1))
```

Sometimes it returns None eventhough it is intended to be `True`. I'm not sure what happened?

Comment: The example code here prints either `True` or `False`; you example code is probably *not* reflecting your real code.

Comment: Could you paste your real code? The example above works as expected - no *None* returned.

Comment: The code is too long, i do use debug check the step goes to return True, but print None

Comment: There is nothing we can do to help if you don't post the real code, as the code you sent can't return None in any case.

Comment: One possibility is if you caught handled exception and the flow goes out of the block

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's impossible to say without seeing your actual code.  Likely the reason is a code path through your function that doesn't execute a `return` statement.  When the code goes down that path, the function ends with no value returned, and so returns `None`.

Updated:  It sounds like your code looks like this:

```
def b(self, p, data): 
    current = p 
    if current.data == data: 
        return True 
    elif current.data == 1:
        return False 
    else: 
        self.b(current.next, data)
```

That else clause is your `None` path.  You need to return the value that the recursive call returns:

```
    else:
        return self.b(current.next, data)
```

BTW: using recursion for iterative programs like this is not a good idea in Python.  Use iteration instead.  Also, you have no clear termination condition.

Comment: Two exit conditions - two return values - how can it fall off the end of the function given the OPs code?

Comment: It can't, which is why I said, "It's impossible to say without seeing your actual code."  It's very clear that the symptoms described cannot be produced by the code we have.

Comment: my bad - for some reason I read that as you were implying the existing code could possibly do that by your later sentence ;)

Comment: ok, i found the issue, because there is a recusive call,

Comment: def b(self, p, data):
            
    current = p
    if current.data == data:
        return True
    elif current.data == 1
        return False
    else:
        self.b(current.next, data)

Comment: if don't no recusive call, it is ok, otherwise, it return None whatever True or False

Comment: ok, i resolved the issue, instead call self.b(current.next, data), i call it as return(self.b(current.next, data)).

Comment: Thank you! it is because the recursion didn't return the value. It is working now.